# Save all record records using request->all in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravel provides a great help for developers to save all input fields of a form *which is one record* with one line of code.

like if I want to save a form which has multiple input fields and one record to database like:

[image]

then I can save it with below code and it works great:

```
SaveOrder:: create($request->all());
```

---

Now I have a question. If I have multiple records (multiple rows) in a form and I can add new rows with a button pressed. Then how can I save all records with above code?

Like:
[image]

Comment: You could use a loop.

Comment: @Tuim Can you explain how to use it.

Comment: Preferably use the answer below, probably works better then manually looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer for this question is using `foreach` statement. Like:

```
    $CustomerName= $request -> input('CustomerName');
    $ProductId= $request -> input('ProductId');
    $ProductName= $request -> input('ProductName');
    $ProductColor= $request -> input('ProductColor');

    foreach( $ProductId as $key => $n ) {
        SaveOrder::insert(
                    array(
                        'CustomerName' => $CustomerName[$key],
                        'ProductId' => $ProductId[$key],
                        'ProductName' => $ProductPrice[$key],
                        'ProductColor' => $ProductQuantity[$key],
                    )
                    );}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do that using Eloquent :

```
$data = array(
    array('field1'=>'value1', 'field2'=> value2),
    array('field1'=>'value1', 'field2'=> value1),
    //...
);

Model::insert($data);
```

Comment: It has add new button too which adds new row, so how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input names look something like `name[]`, since you can add rows on the fly, you can retrieve the input as an array, and insert them using something like this:

```
$data = [];

$names = request('name');
$product_names = request('product_name');
$product_colour = request('product_colour');
$product_size = request('product_size');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
    // Add checks to make sure indices actually exist, probably using preprocessing in JS
    $data[] = [
        'name' => $names[$i],
        'product_name' => $product_names[$i],
        'product_colour' => $product_colour[$i],
        'product_size' => $product_size[$i],
    ];
}

Model::insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use ***upsert***

If you use Laravel 8 or above, you can make use of `upsert`. Such an useful function to insert or update matching records at the same time.

```
SaveOrder::upsert($request->all(), ['id'], ['CustomerName', 'ProductName', 'ProductColor', 'ProductID']);
```

> The method's first argument consists of the values to insert or update, while the second argument lists the column(s) that uniquely identify records within the associated table. The method's third and final argument is an array of the columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database. The upsert method will automatically set the created_at and updated_at timestamps if timestamps are enabled on the model:

```
Flight::upsert([
  ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego', 'price' => 99],
  ['departure' => 'Chicago', 'destination' => 'New York', 'price' => 150]
], ['departure', 'destination'], ['price']);
```

Read the documentation on [Laravel Upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts)